# Meromorphic function on $\Bbb{P}^n$ is rational

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I was trying to prove that the meromorphic function on the projective n space $\Bbb{CP}^n $ is rational (without using Chow's theorem).

---

To do this we needs to use the fact that the meromorphic function on the projective line is rational.(which is a standard result in Riemann surface theory).

To apply this result , we needs to fixed all the variable and left one variable varies (one variable at a time ), however, I have not idea how to fix variables in projective coordinate $[x_0:...:x_{n+1}]$